# ESP8266 UDP multicast doesn't receive packets

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, wifi

I am currently working on an ESP8266 with the Arduino IDE. I try to implement an ESP8266 in STA mode as multicast receiver. I was writing my code with the help of [this documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/udp-class.html). Especially the following part:

> The WiFiUDP class supports sending and receiving multicast packets on STA interface. When sending a multicast packet, replace udp.beginPacket(addr, port) with udp.beginPacketMulticast(addr, port, WiFi.localIP()). When listening to multicast packets, replace udp.begin(port) with udp.beginMulticast(WiFi.localIP(), multicast_ip_addr, port). You can use udp.destinationIP() to tell whether the packet received was sent to the multicast or unicast address.

Sending to the multicast group with `udp.beginPacketMulticast(addr, port, WiFi.localIP())` and `udp.write(message, messageLength)`works flawlessly.

The receiving part of my code is as follows:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

const char* ssid = "xxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxx";

WiFiUDP Udp;
IPAddress multicastAddress(226,1,1,1);
unsigned int multicastPort = 4096;

char incomingPacket[BUFFER_LENGTH]; 

void setup(){
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //station 
    WiFi.setOutputPower(0);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        delay(500);
    }
    Udp.beginMulticast(WiFi.localIP(), multicastAddress, multicastPort);
}

void loop(){
    int packetLength = Udp.parsePacket(); 
    if(packetLength){
        int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, BUFFER_LENGTH);
        if (len > 0){
            incomingPacket[len] = 0;
            Serial.printf("%s\n", incomingPacket);
        }
    }
}
```

When sending a packet with a [simple](http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html) multicast sender (with matching IP and port), my multicast receiver on my linux laptop receives the packet, but the ESP8266 doesn't.

Maybe some of you have experienced a similar behavior and are able to give me some hints, where I might be wrong.

EDIT:
Since the time I asked this question I completely ruled out an error of the sender on the linux machine by using a verified, 100% working sender. The ESP8266 still doesn't receive any multicast datagramms.

Comment: Are the laptop and the ESP8266 on the same network? If not, you need to adjust TTL for the simple multicast sender. Default is 1.

Comment: yes they are both on my home WiFi

Comment: that still does not work and workaround above does not help. See also https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=15467

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had the same problem.

The unequivocal answer is that there is a power optimization (internal by Espressif) to save power, I guess, and it really creates havoc in the UDP Multicast receiving. Why? I have no idea. Same problem with the ESP32 and ESP8266.

Solution:

```cpp
#include "user_interface.h"
```

and after:

```cpp
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
// the below instructions and now u will receive.
wifi_set_sleep_type(NONE_SLEEP_T); //LIGHT_SLEEP_T and MODE_SLEEP_T
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is a really hard to find solution.