# ESP8266 - How to recieve UDP multicast packet?

Tags: esp8266, networking, tcpip, esp

how can I recieve udp multicast packets in ESP8266? I have this piece of code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid = "my_wifi_ssid";
const char* password = "my_wifi_password";

WiFiUDP Udp;
unsigned int multicastPort = 5683;  // local port to listen on
IPAddress multicastIP(224,0,1,187);

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("connected");

    Udp.beginMulticast(WiFi.localIP(), multicastIP, multicastPort);
    Serial.printf("Now listening at IP %s and %s, UDP port %d\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), multicastIP.toString().c_str(), multicastPort);
}


void loop(){
    int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
    if (packetSize){
    Serial.println("RECEIVED!");
    }
}
```

I wrote it according to [this documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/udp-examples.html) and [this addition to that about adding multicast](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/udp-class.html).
It just set server listening on port 5683.
It prints something like:
Now listening at IP 192.168.1.6 and 224.0.1.187, UDP port 5683
But if I send UDP packet to 224.0.1.187:5683 (eg. via Packet sender app), it doesn't print message "RECEIVED!" (which should, look in loop function). Why ESP8266 is not receiving anything? Strange is, that when I send packet to 192.168.1.6:5683 (its local IP), it prints that message ("RECEIVED!").
Why it works only for local message but not for multicast??

Thanks for every help! :)

PS: [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39957/esp8266-udp-multicast-doesnt-receive-packets) advice didn't help me...

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to call

```
Udp.begin(multicastPort);
```

right before calling

```
Udp.beginMulticast(WiFi.localIP(), multicastIP, multicastPort);
```

At least that's what did the trick for me.